# Unable to set struct instance properties to controller labels/buttons

Tags: swift, struct, segue

I have my segue

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "shopsegue"
    {
    if let destViewController = segue.destination as? shopDetail {
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
        destViewController.selected = [samples[indexPath.row]]
    }
    }
```

my new variable holding the instance of the struct segued

```
    var selected = [shop]()
```

but I am unable to set the labels/buttons of the controller to the struct properties.

Ill try

```
 name.text = selected.namelabel
```

but once "selected." is typed out, none of the autofilling properties show up/are available.  What am i missing?

Comment: You need to include your types so that we know what you're trying to do. What is `shopDetail` in `as? shopDetail` ? And what are you expecting after `selected.` ? We don't know its type either.

Comment: I am confused as to the types you are referring to. shopDetail is the destination controller. after "selected." i would have liked/expected for the struct properties to come up. I was looking for "name.text = selected.nameLabel" to appear.

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned `selected` as an array of `shop` objects.

Instead of this you need to assign `selected` as a single `shop` object.

Try this:

```
var selected = shop()
name.text = selected.namelabel
```

Comment: when I change the variable though, I am presented with the error "Missing argument for parameter "name" in call"

Comment: Can you show the code of shop class? Have you creates any intializer in it? What is name in this? And where are you creating this shop class object?

Comment: are you looking for the shop table controller? AKA, the one I am segue-ing from?

Comment: If you are segue-ing from shop table controller what is the need of creating shop object in it? Please clear the context. And the problem you are facing might be due to the initializer that takes  "name" in its call.

Comment: I am confused by the question. In the segue, I am attaching the sender indexPath to the samples array to pass one instance onto shopDetail

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, I just had to set my variable a little bit different. I didn't have to bother with an array or parentheses instance, just a simple

```
 var selected: shop!
```

Comment: You must specify your requirement in the question clearly.